# Is $s(t) = 1/(1+t^2)$ a bounded function? If so, find the smallest $M$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Is $s(t) = 1/(1+t^2)$ a bounded function? If so, find the smallest $M$

I know that a function is bounded if there is a number $M$ such that $|f(x)|<M$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$.

After sketching $s(t)$, I found that the function is indeed bounded, between $y=0$ and $y=1$.

How do I express the smallest $M$? I know that $s(t)≠0$, but what is the smallest $M$ possible?

Comment: Since $0\leq s(t)\leq s(0)=1$ and $s$ is continuous, $M=1$.

Comment: Since your inequality is strict, I would assume $1+\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the smallest $M$ is such that for every $M'$ smaller than $M$, the statement $|f(x)|<M$ is no longer true for all values of $x$. Therefore, if you find some $x$ for which $f(x)=1$, then you know that the smallest $M$ is larger or equal to $1$.

If you also prove that $M=1$ satisfies your requirements (and mind you, saying "I sketched it and saw it is so" is not a good answer), you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I go about proving that M=1?

Comment: @McB By proving that for all $x$, the value $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is smaller than or equal to $1$. That should be really really easy, since the value is one, divided by one *plus something*.